# Prove if this function is surjective, injective or bijective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider the function

$$f (x) = x^2 + 2x + 6$$

given by

$$f :   (-\infty, 0] \longrightarrow [0,\infty)$$

How can I know if this function is surjective, injective or bijective?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Use the definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

$f(0)=f(-2)$

$f(x)=(x+1)^2+5\ge5$